# CSS/HTML Have object pushed by scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have this page with a sidebar and I want the content in the sidebar to move down with the page but only if you scroll past it. So If you are at the top of the page it would be at the top of the sidebar but if you are at the bottom it would be at the top of the screen. How would you do that? I tried using `position: fixed`but that just moves it with the screen no matter what and I only want it to move if the top reaches it.

Gif of Webpage with sidebar content that has the position fixed:

[image]

Here's the CSS of the content:

```
#content-list {position: fixed;}
#content-list ul {padding: 0px; list-style: none;}
#content-list li { padding-bottom: 25px; }
```

Here's the HTML of the content:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <nav id="content-list">
        Page Content:
        <ul>
            <a href="#quick-description"><li>Quick Description</li></a>
            <a href="#help-menu"><li>Help Menu</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I would like to be able to do this using only CSS/HTML if possible (No javascript etc.)

Full demo:

```css
/* imports a Google font */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora);

/* creates an 800px-wide space centered on the page, to constrain line width. it also  specifies a default typeface and line height for the entire body of the document */

body {
  background: #551A8B;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}
#body {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 150%;
}
#main {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-family: Lora;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
}
.content {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
}
.sidebar {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 20px;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  background: #450A7B;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
}
#content-list {
  position: fixed;
}
#content-list ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
#content-list li {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
#title {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 10%;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Oswald;
  background-color: #35006B;
  font-size: 120%;
}
#footer {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-color: #35006B;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 20%;
  height: 10%;
}
a:link {
  color: #FFE303;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
  color: #E3701A;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h2 {
  font-family: Oswald;
}
/* Setup the dropdown menu at the top of the screen */

.menu ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  background: #35006B
}
.menu li > ul {
  display: none;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background: #25005B
}
.menu li:hover > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  font-size: 80%;
  width: 200px;
}
.menu li li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10% 75% 10% 10%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFE303;
}
/* Set images to a certain size */

.large-image {
  width: 50%
}
.small-image {
  width: 25%
}
#links {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>NecroTheif: Maze Generator Project</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>Maze Generator</h1>
      <ul class="menu">
        <a href="#">
          <li>
            Features
            <ul>
              <a href="about.html">
                <li>About</li>
              </a>
              <a href="generation.html">
                <li>Generating Mazes</li>
              </a>
              <a href="editing.html">
                <li>Editing Mazes</li>
              </a>
              <a href="settings.html">
                <li>Settings</li>
              </a>
              <a href="saveopen.html">
                <li>Save/Open</li>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="MazeCreator.exe">
          <li>Download</li>
        </a>
        <a href="api.html">
          <li>API</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="sidebar">

      </div>
      <div id="main">
        <h2 id="quick-description">Quick Description</h2>
        <img class="large-image" src="https://i.gyazo.com/93f60cc74d13175ce5aee548cc020b10.png" alt="Picture of the maze creator program." />
        <p class="content">The maze creator program is a program that allows you to create mazes of any size with ease. You can create mazes either by using an algorithm to generate them or building them yourself in the creator (You can even combine the two by generating
          a maze and then editing it!). You then can save these files as .maz files to be loaded into games or to be edited later in the maze creator!</p>
        <h2 id="help-menu">Help Menu</h2>
        <img class="small-image" src="https://i.gyazo.com/55ec91a6523562ca82341510c7bdde43.png" alt="Picture of the top of the help menu." />
        <img class="small-image" src="https://i.gyazo.com/d121313f333eba42faa37220aa599bb7.png" alt="Picture of the bottom of the help menu." />
        <p class="content">This menu in the maze creator shows the basic controls of the creator. Open it by clicking Help or pressing Ctrl+H</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <nav id="content-list">
          Page Content:
          <ul>
            <a href="#quick-description">
              <li>Quick Description</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#help-menu">
              <li>Help Menu</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div id="links">
        <a href="../index.html">Main Page</a>
      </div>
      <p>Developer: Andrew Wetmore (aka NecroTheif)</p>
      <p>Last Updated: 11/03/15</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can u show completed cod e

Comment: The technique is called "sticky". There are plenty of ways to make an element sticky: https://www.google.com.au/#q=javascript+sticky

Comment: You can do this with pure HTML/CSS by adding `#content-list { position: sticky; top: 0; }` This will work on [**Firefox and Safari**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) currently. [**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v13m9ur5/)

Comment: That actually worked! Is there any way to make it work in any browser?

Comment: For the moment that's only possible with JavaScript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4813913/manoj-kumar) says in a comment this can be done using

```
position: sticky; position: -webkit-sticky;
```

Sadly this only works in Firefox and Safari (For now, see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) for more info). I went with that and for browsers that don't support it I used this simple javascript (Which does not require JQuery and in my opinion creates a "cleaner" look than most complicated sticky sidebars) and anything I wanted to be sticky was of class "sticky"

```
// Try to give it sticky position first
function loadStickies(){
    var sticky = document.getElementById("content-list");
    sticky.style.position = "-webkit-sticky";
    sticky.style.position = "sticky";
    positionStickies();
}

// If giving it sticky position didn't work do it manually
function positionStickies() {
    var sticky = document.getElementById("content-list");
    if(sticky.style.position !== "sticky" && sticky.style.position !== "-webkit-sticky"){
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > sticky.parentNode.offsetTop || document.body.scrollTop > sticky.parentNode.offsetTop) 
            sticky.style.position = "fixed";
        else 
            sticky.style.position = "relative";
    }
}

window.onload = loadStickies;
window.onresize = positionStickies;
window.onscroll = positionStickies;
window.onclick = click;
```

**EDIT**

To make the script work in IE and Firefox you must use document.documentElement as well as document.body.

Complete Demo:

```js
// Try to give it sticky position first
function loadStickies(){
    var sticky = document.getElementById("content-list");
 sticky.style.position = "-webkit-sticky";
    sticky.style.position = "sticky";
    positionStickies();
}

// If giving it sticky position didn't work do it manually
function positionStickies() {
    var sticky = document.getElementById("content-list");
    if(sticky.style.position !== "sticky" && sticky.style.position !== "-webkit-sticky"){
     if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > sticky.parentNode.offsetTop || document.body.scrollTop > sticky.parentNode.offsetTop) 
            sticky.style.position = "fixed";
        else 
            sticky.style.position = "relative";
    }
}

window.onload = loadStickies;
window.onresize = positionStickies;
window.onscroll = positionStickies;
window.onclick = click;
```

```css
/* imports a Google font */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora);

/* creates an 800px-wide space centered on the page, to constrain line width. it also  specifies a default typeface and line height for the entire body of the document */

body {
  background: #551A8B;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}
#body {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 150%;
}
#main {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-family: Lora;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
}
.content {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
}
.sidebar {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 20px;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  background: #450A7B;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black inset;
}
#content-list {
  top: 0; padding-top:10px;
}
#content-list ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
#content-list li {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
#title {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 10%;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Oswald;
  background-color: #35006B;
  font-size: 120%;
}
#footer {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-color: #35006B;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 20%;
  height: 10%;
}
a:link {
  color: #FFE303;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
  color: #E3701A;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h2 {
  font-family: Oswald;
}
/* Setup the dropdown menu at the top of the screen */

.menu ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  background: #35006B
}
.menu li > ul {
  display: none;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background: #25005B
}
.menu li:hover > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  font-size: 80%;
  width: 200px;
}
.menu li li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10% 75% 10% 10%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFE303;
}
/* Set images to a certain size */

.large-image {
  width: 50%
}
.small-image {
  width: 25%
}
#links {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>NecroTheif: Maze Generator Project</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>Maze Generator</h1>
      <ul class="menu">
        <a href="#">
          <li>
            Features
            <ul>
              <a href="about.html">
                <li>About</li>
              </a>
              <a href="generation.html">
                <li>Generating Mazes</li>
              </a>
              <a href="editing.html">
                <li>Editing Mazes</li>
              </a>
              <a href="settings.html">
                <li>Settings</li>
              </a>
              <a href="saveopen.html">
                <li>Save/Open</li>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="MazeCreator.exe">
          <li>Download</li>
        </a>
        <a href="api.html">
          <li>API</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="sidebar">

      </div>
      <div id="main">
        <h2 id="quick-description">Quick Description</h2>
        <img class="large-image" src="https://i.gyazo.com/93f60cc74d13175ce5aee548cc020b10.png" alt="Picture of the maze creator program." />
        <p class="content">The maze creator program is a program that allows you to create mazes of any size with ease. You can create mazes either by using an algorithm to generate them or building them yourself in the creator (You can even combine the two by generating
          a maze and then editing it!). You then can save these files as .maz files to be loaded into games or to be edited later in the maze creator!</p>
        <h2 id="help-menu">Help Menu</h2>
        <img class="small-image" src="https://i.gyazo.com/55ec91a6523562ca82341510c7bdde43.png" alt="Picture of the top of the help menu." />
        <img class="small-image" src="https://i.gyazo.com/d121313f333eba42faa37220aa599bb7.png" alt="Picture of the bottom of the help menu." />
        <p class="content">This menu in the maze creator shows the basic controls of the creator. Open it by clicking Help or pressing Ctrl+H</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <nav id="content-list">
          Page Content:
          <ul>
            <a href="#quick-description">
              <li>Quick Description</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#help-menu">
              <li>Help Menu</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div id="links">
        <a href="../index.html">Main Page</a>
      </div>
      <p>Developer: Andrew Wetmore (aka NecroTheif)</p>
      <p>Last Updated: 11/03/15</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The term for this is 'Sticky sidebar', so you want it to always stick to the top of the page when the user scrolls.

There's millions of plugins for it, I'm particularly fond of this one:

**DEMO**: http://spoiledmilk.com/demos/sticky-sidebar/

This [article](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/sticky-sidebar/) explains in detail how to implement it and what it does exactly.

Comment: I would like to do this pure CSS/HTML.

Comment: You can 't, css doesn't know the position of the scroll, or the top of the window